# Asynchronous call disregarded by Awesomium

Tags: c#, javascript, asynchronous, awesomium

in Awesomium-sharp, I wrote my C# code like this:

```
WebControl webControl = new WebControl();
webControl.CreateObject("external");
SetObjectCallback("external", "JSCallback", OnJSCallback);


private int count = 0;

    private void OnJSCallback(object sender, JSCallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
        MessageBox.Show("hi");

        if (count == 0)
        {
            Thread worker = new Thread(func =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    OnReturn();
                });
            worker.Start();
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            Thread worker = new Thread(func =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                OnReturn();
            });
            worker.Start();
        }
        count++;
    }

    private void OnReturn()
    {
            webControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart) delegate()
            {
                webControl.CallJavascriptFunction("", "CallFromNative", new JSValue[] {new JSValue("hello")});
            });
    }
```

and the javascript code is like this:

```
external.JSCallback("hello ", "world");
external.JSCallback("wtf ", "dude");
```

The strange problem is that the second call from Javascript seems to be diregarded and 
never executed. 
What's wrong with my code? and btw, the version of AwesomiumSharp is V1.6.6

Answer (score 0):

Seems almost fine to me.

Id do it like this though:

```
 webView.Callback += new EventHandler<CallbackEventArgs>(webView_Callback);

    webView.CreateObject("client");
    webView.SetObjectCallback("client", "message");

    void webView_Callback(object sender, CallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CallbackName == "message")
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Args[0].ToString());
    }
```

It should work fine what you're doing. Are you sure you're even executing function second time? alert("blabla"); message.client("test", "test2"), and see what happens if you wait a little and then do it.

As far I've used Awesomium callback systemm, it works nicely